# virtualization enabled in BIOS but not seen in virtualbox

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtualization, intel-haxm

Someone know why I can't see nested VT-x option in virtualbox ?

my setup is:

- OS : windows 10 Home.
- CPU : i7-4510U.
- Virtualization : enabled in BIOS.

I tried disabling windows features `Plateform virtual Machine` and `Hypervisor` But nothing is working. The command `systeminfo` on CMD says yes for all Hyper-v options.

VT-x is required by Android emulator which I want to start on  a ubutu virtual machine.

Comment: Do you have another virtualizing app running?  Try removing those if so. Make sure Hyper-V is disable in Windows Features.

Comment: but Hyper-v does not exist in windows 10 family although the command above mentioned displays Hyper-v things. Also i have a fresh installation with only Chrome and virtualbox.

Comment: @miraclegenuis - Hyper-V absolutely is a feature of Windows 10, Windows 10 Professional, if your running Windows 10 Home it does not exist.  However, that doesn’t stop you from enabling VT-x

Comment: @Ramhound I updated my post, it is windows 10 Home not Family (which it does not exist). VT-x is indeed activated (shown in Task manager)  But virtualbox not detecting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the same yesterday. Shut down the VM (save doesn't work) and VirtualBox, and on the command line:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm vm-name --nested-hw-virt on
```

It should now be enabled in the VM settings.

Comment: I already tried it out but without the "on" keywords as the documentation   [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/admin/nested-virt.html)  leads me to undestand. Anyway thank you a lot that the solution .

Comment: @miraclegenuis It's needed  :-)

Comment: yes it was better if vboxmanage can tell one that this option needs on/off arguments. Thank you again i waste a lot of time on it.

Comment: Me too, mate, me too... :-D